# Google Tag Manager - gtag() events custom not working send request on WordPress website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

I have an issue with Google Tag Manager on WordPress Website, the issue if add code gtag() events custom not working to send the request 'collect'. But if using gtag('event', 'gtm.init') is working has sent a request 'collect'.

**gtag('event', 'gtm.init')** is working

[image]

**gtag('event', custom) is not working**
[image]

**But if using "send_to: GA Code" is working**
[image]